# parameter &usqp=mq331AQCCAE= at the url from AMP

Tags: amp-html

Since some days there are reffers from AMP with the `&usqp=mq331AQCCAE=`paramater at the url. I must rewrite this to clear my analytics reports. So:
Do some one know what is it?

Comment: A [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/K8xwJvcU6Hs/mDY22b0bBwAJ) has been opened. Keep track of further updates.

Comment: And now: &usqp=mq331AQCCAE= again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ask [Malte Ubl on Twitter](https://twitter.com/lovntol/status/907979708167593985). His anwser is:

> This controls an experiment on the AMP cache.

Comment: And now its changed to usqp=mq331AQECAEgAQ==

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Google Analytics forum](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Odd-AMP-page-URL-extension-coming-from-google-organic-traffic/m-p/1171689#), the said unusual parameter has been removed. Kindly confirm if this has been reflected on yours as well.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. I can't see refferer with this parameter anymore.

Comment: Good job! You can mark this as answered so community knows problem is not persistent anymore. :)

Comment: And now &usqp=mq331AQCCAE= again. It will be interesting what kind of testing it is.